# Manipulating SQL string result table

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, trim

I'm trying to change the result set so that the OriginalName column string is rewritten to the output table. There are 2 scenarios id like to change this string according to:

1. Reading the `OriginalName` from left to right IF the first date value found is in the form `YYYYMMDD` then trim everything from the right and append `.txt`

   - For example, for `OriginalName := "TPV02002_KBA_HOUSE_Daily_Claims_20221009_221010091706003.txt"`
     Id want the output result to be changed to `TPV02002_KBA_HOUSE_Daily_Claims_20221009.txt`
2. Same change but instead IF is the first date format seen `YYYY-MM-DD`

   - For example, for `OriginalName := "TPV00165_Paid Claims 2022-10-09_221010080406124.txt"`
   - Desired output `"TPV00165_Paid Claims 2022-10-09.txt"`

```sql
SELECT
    RXInboundFileQueue.OriginalName,
    'rx' AS Filetype,
    RXInboundFileQueue.FileCatalogedOn

FROM
    EDIPlatform.dbo.RXInboundFileQueue

WHERE
    FileCatalogedOn >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())

ORDER BY
    OriginalName DESC,
    FileCatalogedOn
```

---

[image]

Comment: So in other words, remove all digits and underscore after the last underscore character...?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is indeed that regular, just `STUFF()` the extraneous numerals with an empty string:

```
SELECT
    RXInboundFileQueue.OriginalName,
    STUFF(
        RXInboundFileQueue.OriginalName,
        LEN(RXInboundFileQueue.OriginalName)-19,
        16,
        ''
    ) AS OriginalNameFormatted,
    'rx' AS Filetype,
    RXInboundFileQueue.FileCatalogedOn

FROM
    EDIPlatform.dbo.RXInboundFileQueue

WHERE
    FileCatalogedOn >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())

ORDER BY
    OriginalName DESC,
    FileCatalogedOn
```

If the data gets more irregular, research regular expressions and pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RXInboundFileQueue.OriginalName OldOriginalName
,SUBSTRING(RXInboundFileQueue.OriginalName, 0, 
LEN(RXInboundFileQueue.OriginalName) - CHARINDEX('_', 
REVERSE(RXInboundFileQueue.OriginalName), 0) + 1) + '.txt' 
NewOriginalName
FROM EDIPlatform.dbo.RXInboundFileQueue
WHERE FileCatalogedOn >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I think this should be enough for the task. :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of approaches:

```
SELECT Q.OriginalName, U.UpdatedName, U.UpdatedName2, C.*
FROM EDIPlatform.dbo.RXInboundFileQueue Q
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        pos1 = CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(Q.OriginalName)),
        pos2 = CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(Q.OriginalName)),
        pos3 = PATINDEX('%[.][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][_]%', REVERSE(Q.OriginalName))
) C
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        UpdatedName =
            CASE WHEN pos1 > 0 AND pos2 > pos1
            THEN REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(Q.OriginalName), pos1 + 1, pos2 - pos1, ''))
            ELSE Q.OriginalName
            END,
        UpdatedName2 =
            CASE WHEN pos3 > 0
            THEN REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(Q.OriginalName), pos3 + 1, 16, ''))
            ELSE Q.OriginalName
            END
) U
```

The first just looks at the delimiters. The second looks for the specific sequence of underscore + 15 digits + dot.

See [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LNO2bNFY).